# Promises vs async await behaviour javascript. Concurrency mode

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

i'm trying to avoid concurrency of a async function in order to wait for the first call of this function to be finished before i can call it again the same function :

```js
const disallowConcurrency = (fn) => {
  let inprogressPromise = Promise.resolve();

  return async(...args) => {
    await inprogressPromise;
    inprogressPromise = inprogressPromise.then(() => fn(...args));
  };
};

const initCmp = async(arg) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    console.log('executed');
    setTimeout(() => res(console.log(arg)), 1000);
  });
};
const cmpConcurrentFunction = disallowConcurrency(initCmp);
cmpConcurrentFunction('I am called 1 second later');
cmpConcurrentFunction('I am called 2 seconds later');
```

So here i'm creating a closure with a promise as a value passed to the inner function.
The return function will wait for the previous call ( in the first run it's a resolved Promise ) and the will assign to `inprogressPromise` the promise returned by the `then` which in this case will be a new Promise returned by the `initCmp` function. So next time we call the function it will wait for the previous one to be done. At least this is how i'm understanding it. Did i get it right?

But i don't understand why this keeps working if i remove the `await inprogressPromise`for example like this :

```
    const disallowConcurrency = (fn) => {
  let inprogressPromise = Promise.resolve();

  return async (...args) => {
    inprogressPromise = inprogressPromise.then(() => fn(...args));
  };
};
```

So the `await` is not necessary? Why?

Further more i was expecting this to work :

```
 const disallowConcurrency = (fn) => {
  let inprogressPromise = Promise.resolve();

  return async (...args) => {
    await inprogressPromise;
    inprogressPromise = fn(...args);
  };
};
```

Because i was thinking that first i'm awaiting for the previous promise to be done and then i would call and assign the returned promise on the `inprogressPromise`.

But it's not working and the two functions are called at the same time.

Can someone clarify me what's going on here?

If you try the code you will see that the second call

```
cmpConcurrentFunction("I am called 2 seconds later")
```

will wait for the first promise to be done.

Basically i have written a node package that gets imported into the browser in a web app through npm.
This node package library has an init function that has some async code and can be called multiple time in different part of the code.
If is called a second time for example i want to be sure that the first execution will be done before trying to execute the code again.

But my point is trying to understand why that code works and why it doesn't if i use the last version

Thanks!

Comment: `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar that "hides" a `Promise` + `.then()`

Comment: `await inprogressPromise;` - You're `await`ing an already resolved `Promise`. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: @ggorlen as far as I can tell the OP is not trying to stop a function being async, just to stop different async functions running concurrently, but to wait for any in progress one to finish before launching a new one.

Comment: What i'm trying to achive is that i might call the same async function twice and i need to be sure that the first one has been finished before calling again the function. 

Basically i have a library with an init function. This init function is doing an async task and this library can be imported in different part of the code and the init function can be called multiple times. If this happen i need to be sure that the previous execution is done before calling it again. 
The example that i shared works, as the second function call wait for the first to be done

Comment: It's a node library that gets imported through npm and gets executed on the browser by React

Comment: I think you're saying that the code in the first snippet in fact works? if so, I'm surprised, as you don't `await` either of the calls to `cmpConcurrentFunction`.

Comment: It's a library that i'm writing, but this function can be called multiple time across the application and if one has already been called i want to be sure that it will complete before it gets called again.

Regarding the snippet i provided, yes, the first code works. At least from my understanding. If you run it on the browser you will see that the second promise gets resolved after the first one is done

Comment: Gotcha, I think I understand the question now. I suggest converting the snippets to be runnable browser snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions, let me first try to explain how your code is working.

#### Understanding how your code works

Following steps explain the execution of your code:

1. Script execution start
2. Call `disallowConcurrency` function, passing in the `initCmp` as an argument. `cmpConcurrentFunction` is assigned the return value of `disallowConcurrency` function
3. Call `cmpConcurrentFunction` for the first time, passing in `'I am called 1 second later'` as an argument. During this invocation, `inprogressPromise` is a resolved promise returned by `Promise.resolve()`. Awaiting it pauses the function execution.
4. Call `cmpConcurrentFunction` for the second time, passing in `'I am called 2 seconds later'` as an argument. During this second invocation, `inprogressPromise` is still a resolved promise returned by `Promise.resolve()`. Awaiting it pauses the function execution.
5. Synchronous execution of script ends here. Event loop can now start processing the micro-task queue
6. Function paused as a result of first invocation of `cmpConcurrentFunction` is resumed, calling `then()` method on the promise returned by `Promise.resolve()`. The value of the `inprogressPromise` is updated by assigning it a new promise returned by `inprogressPromise.then(...)`
7. Function paused as a result of second invocation of `cmpConcurrentFunction` is resumed. From step 6, we know that `inprogressPromise` is now a promise returned by `inprogressPromise.then(...)`. So, calling `then()` on it, we are simply creating a promise chain, adding a new `then()` method call at the end of the promise chain created in step 6.

   At this point, we have a chain that looks like this:

   ```
   inProgressPromise
     .then(() => fn('I am called 1 second later'))
     .then(() => fn('I am called 2 seconds later'))
   ```
8. Callback function of the first `then` method is called, which in turn calls the `fn` argument, which is `initCmp` function. Calling `initCmp` sets up a timer that resolves the promise `initCmp` returns after 1 second. When the promise is resolved after 1 second, `'I am called 1 second later'` is logged on the console.
9. When the promise returned by the first call to `initComp` function in the callback function of first `then` method, is resolved, it resolves the promise returned by the first `then` method. This leads to the invocation of the callback function of the second `then` method. This again calls the `initComp` function, which then returns a new promise that is resolved after another 1 second.

This explains why you see `'I am called 2 seconds later'` logged on the console after 2 seconds.

---

Now answering your questions:

> But i don't understand why this keeps working if i remove the await
> inprogressPromise

`await inprogressPromise` serves no purpose in your code other than pausing the calls to `cmpConcurrentFunction` function. Both calls await the same promise that is returned by `Promise.resolve()`.

> So the await is not necessary? Why?

Because the output you see on the console is not because of `await`, but because of the promise chain (step 7 above) that is constructed as a result of two invocations of the `cmpConcurrentFunction` function.

> Further more i was expecting this to work :
>
> ```
> const disallowConcurrency = (fn) => {   
>   let inprogressPromise = Promise.resolve();
>
>   return async (...args) => {
>     await inprogressPromise;
>     inprogressPromise = fn(...args);   
>   }; 
> };
> ```

The above code doesn't works as your original code because now the promise chain isn't constructed which is key to the output your original code produces.

With this implementation of `disallowConcurrency`, your code is executed as explained below:

1. Call `cmpConcurrentFunction` function, passing in `'I am called 1 second later'` as an argument
2. Awaiting `inprogressPromise` pauses the function execution
3. Call `cmpConcurrentFunction` for the second time, passing in `'I am called 2 seconds later'` as an argument
4. Awaiting `inprogressPromise` pauses the function execution. At this point, both invocations of `cmpConcurrentFunction` are paused and both function invocations are awaiting the *same* promise that was created as a result of calling `Promise.resolve()`.

   This is the key point here: both invocations of `cmpConcurrentFunction` function are awaiting the *same* promise that was created by `Promise.resolve()`. Why are both invocations awaiting the same promise? Because the `cmpConcurrentFunction` is invoked for the second time *before* the first invocation of `cmpConcurrentFunction` is resumed and calls the `initComp` function
5. Resume the first invocation of `cmpConcurrentFunction`, call the `initComp` function and assign its return value to `inprogressPromise`.

   Calling `initComp` function sets up a timer that resolves the promise `initComp` function returns after 1 second
6. Resume the second invocation of `cmpConcurrentFunction`, call the `initComp` function and assign its return value to `inprogressPromise`, overwriting the current value of `inprogressPromise` which is the promise returned by the first call to `initComp` function.

   Calling `initComp` function sets up a timer that resolves the promise `initComp` function returns after 1 second

At this point, `initComp` function has been invoked twice, setting up two separate timers that resolve their respective promise after 1 second each.

To summarize the differences between the original implementation of `disallowConcurrency` function and this one is that in the original implementation, you have a promise chain which resolves the promises sequentially whereas in the second implementation, you have two *separate* promises (that don't depend on each other) and they are resolved after 1 second each.

Comment: If you try to execute the code shown you will see that the second console.log will be executed after 2 seconds, because it will wait for the first promise to be resolved.
I mean the executor of the function will be called immediatly, agree, but the resolve will wait for the first one to be resolved before resolving

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to give an answer as detailed as this. Really appreciate it.
I have a question though. In the last code i'm awaiting the promise ( which i though it should pause the execution of the next line untile the promise is resolved ) and then i'm assigning to inprogressPromise the new promise returned by the fn invocation. With this i was expecting to resolve the first promise and THEN calling the second one .  But i guess i'm missing something

Comment: I'm also not convinced about the explanation for why the `await` version doesn't work. It's clearly in two separate chains, but since `inprogressPromise` is shared, I can see how you'd expect one function to execute `inprogressPromise = fn(...args);` first, causing the other one to hit `await inprogressPromise` and block until the first finishes, just like `then`, before finally being able to execute `fn`.

Comment: I have added the detailed explanation of why the second implementation of `disallowConcurrency` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Now it's much more clear, thanks again for the time and the detailed explanation.So in both cases the two calls at the beginning are waiting for the same Promise.resolve() but the difference is that by synchronously chaining the return value of one promise into the then of the other will execute them one after the other

Comment: Exactly! In the original code, you create a promise chain that executes sequentially whereas in the second code example, you DO NOT have a promise chain; instead you just have two separate promises that don't depend on each other and they both are resolved after 1 second.